# How do I deselect a tool?

Tags: stardew-valley

I have one of the items in the backpack selected at all time. If there is an empty space, I can use it to deselect, but if all are filled, how do you deselect a tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. I suggest having the Scythe equipped normally, as it doesn't use energy when accidentally swung, and doesn't have any effect when right clicked.